# Angular Velocity of a car

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-velocity

Given a time $t$ in seconds, and a $\theta$ of the curve, and  the radius $r$ in meters, how would I calculate the angular velocity of a car going through the curve in $t$ seconds?

I think it will be  $\omega=\frac{\Delta\theta}{\Delta t}$.

What is $\Delta \theta$?

Comment: How can you "know" it is $\frac{\Delta \theta}{\Delta t}$ without knowing what $\Delta \theta$ is?

Comment: Sorry, fixed the wording.

Comment: I don't see any intuition in this question. It seems to me a homework problem.

Comment: It is a example from my textbook, I am working through trying to catch-up. This problem just seemed far too simple of an answer. So it is kinda a homework problem, I can delete it if you would like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is $\Delta \theta$?

For a general time-dependent function $f(t)$:

$$f'(t)=\frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}t}=\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{\Delta f}{\Delta t}$$

where:

$$\Delta f=f(t+\Delta t)-f(t)$$

So for $\theta(t)$, $\theta'=\frac{\text{d}\theta}{\text{d}t}$, where:

$$\boxed{\Delta \theta=\theta(t+\Delta t)-\theta(t)}$$

And:

$$\frac{\text{d}\theta}{\text{d}t}=\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{\theta(t+\Delta t)-\theta(t)}{\Delta t}$$

**Example-** let:

$$\theta(t)=\theta_0+\omega t$$

Then:

$$\frac{\text{d}\theta}{\text{d}t}=\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{\theta_0+\omega(t+\Delta t)-(\theta_0+\omega t)}{\Delta t}$$
$$=\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{\omega\Delta t}{\Delta t}=\omega$$

Comment: So, for example, if $t = 6s$ and $\theta = 90^∘$ would $$\omega = \lim_{\Delta t \to 1} \frac{90(6s + \Delta t) -  90(6))}{\Delta t} = 90?$$

Comment: No. Notice that the limit in his answer is $\Delta t \to 0$, and not to 1. However, if you know that $\theta(t)$ is a linear function (the speed is constant) then you do not need to try to work it out this way.

Comment: I misspoke, I meant to say I think it is $\omega=\frac{\Delta\theta}{\Delta t}$. I wasn't sure, but since it is meant to be a car taking a turn wouldn't it be constantly changing in speed? So this formula would be the one used. Also the 1 was a mistype and can't correct it any more. :(

Comment: $\omega=\frac{\Delta\theta}{\Delta t}$ is correct **only for** uniform rotation, see my example. Thanks for the upvote.

Answer (score 1):

$\Delta \theta$ is the angle that the car travels in a time $\Delta t$. For simplicity, we will say that the car is going at constant speed in a circle. Since it is constant, we can just take averages and ignore that limit.

Suppose in time $\Delta t = 5s$, the car goes in a full circle, $\Delta \theta = 360^\circ$. That means that the speed (just like how rate = distance/time), is equal to $72^\circ/s$.

Now consider the case in which the speed is not constant, but changing. How can we define an angular velocity then? What we would have to do is take the instantaneous angular velocity. That means, in a very short time $\Delta t$, it travels a very small angle $\Delta \theta$. If we make $\Delta t$ as small as possible, the speed at that instant will be approximately $\Delta \theta/\Delta t$.

**For your question**, we want to know which scenario applies to us. If the car is going at a constant speed around the corner, we can use the first example. That is, we wouldn't need to use instantaneous angular velocity, because the instantaneous angular velocity is constant around the entire track, equal to the average angular velocity. However, if the speed is always changing, you would need to find the instantaneous angular velocity, as a function of time.

Comment: Thank you for answering I wasn't sure if it was as simple as it is! It does not specify if the speed changes so I assumed it does not.